# Problems booting ubuntu after unmounting or formating HDD (data disk)?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, unmount

After I deleted the partition on my internal HDD (only datadisk) and therefore unmounted the HDD I could not access Ubuntu 16.04 (Kernel 4.11) anymore with an error showing up
`Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.`

My actual plan was to format the HDD to `exfat` so I could use it for a future dual boot for Windows as well but I did not format the HDD to `exfat` yet or mount it again.
The whole system should actually be running on my SSD, so I do not understand how unmounting the HDD can cause such an error...
All the recovery attempts I tried did fail until now and I can only access the boot menu and get stuck in there.

All the error messages I could find are:

- `ACPI Error: [_OSI] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND 
  (20170119/psargs-363)`
- `APCI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PAGD._STA]
  (Node ffff9fa6ee4d4028), AE_NOT_FOUND (20170119/psparse-543)`
- `iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: capa flags index 3 larger than supported by driver`
- `Failed to start Braille Device Support`
- `dev-disk-by\x2partlabel-primary.device: Dev dev-disk-by\x2partlabel-primart.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4`
- `Timed out waiting for decixe dev-sdb1.device.` -> `sdb1` is my HDD
  and then
- `Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization`

Can anyone tell my if I did something wrong or if this error is repairable?

Comment: You may have more than one problem. 1) you're running an unsupported configuration with kernel 4.11, 2) your /etc/fstab probably has a mount for the partition sdb1 that used to be there, and isn't any more, 3) if you're going to share data between Windows and Ubuntu, NTFS would be a more common choice.

Comment: It took some time until I started to work on this Laptop again and somehow I missed that there were answers, so sorry for my delay! But thanks a lot heynnema for your help, NTFS is a good idea actually! I will check out the mount partition. The problem is just that I cannot even boot into Linux anymore as soon as I format the HDD. With my last try this week the same error just happened when saving data on the HDD. I will check the HDD for errors first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error --"Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1" means that it is trying to mount the HDD, and failing because it can't.

Edit the file /etc/fstab, comment out the reference to the HDD.
You should now be able to boot.

Comment: It took some time until I started to work on this Laptop again and somehow I missed that there were answers, so sorry for my delay! But thanks a lot. I will try to see if I can change the reference for the mount. Thanks for your help.